# Jekyll multiple pages using the same template

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm aware you can use `_layouts` and in your pages do something like

```
---
layout: some_layout
title: Home
---
```

So say I have 20 pages. All using the same template but slightly different content and stuff inside.

Instead of creating 20 different `pages.html` files with different names and different permalinks.

Is there a way to create 1 `page.html` and based on the permalink change what's inside the `{{ content }}`?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your-slug.md files. Let them all use the same layout, like this:

```
---
layout: some_layout
title: Your title
---
```

In the layout file (some_layout.html) you put some logic, like this:

```
{% if page.url contains '/your-slug' %}Put this on the screen.{% endif %}
```

Comment: Did that actually answer the question? I thought the original poster asked for a way to have a single page.html (or in your case a single your-slug.md) and not lots of them.

Comment: That seems impossible to me, unless you use a page generator. The layout trick above requires one layout file and 20 .md files with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

You could organize the 20 pages under a collection and assign defaults on the collection.
For example, say your collection is labelled **`docs`**, then all those 20 pages need to be placed inside a directory named `_docs`, at the root of your source directory. Following that configure your collection to use the layout `some_layout` for its documents.

```
# _config.yml

# enable rendering on your collection(s)
collections:
  docs:
    output: true
  another_collection:
    output: true

# set defaults on your collection. (note the indentation..)
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      type: docs
      path: _docs
    values:
      layout: some_layout # The layout for this collections' files
  -
    scope:
      type: another_collection
      [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this yet, but there is a closed github issue:  https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/16

There are suggestions to write/use a jekyll plugin like the ones below. These are links from the issue and their state is unknown to me.

- https://github.com/ixti/ixti.github.io/blob/source/_plugins/categories.rb
- https://github.com/rfelix/my_jekyll_extensions/tree/master/category_gen

how to write a plugin: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/